# Can the SE staff give this site more love and attention, we are only two days old? :-)

Tags: discussion

With regards to tag edits, this has been holding me up for a few hours.

[image]

Also with the limit of 20 edits I tend to hit the limit after a few hours of editing tags.

Can the SE staff check and clear the tag edit queues more frequently, hopefully every 4 hours during working hours.

---

**EDIT**

Also can the system be changed so that if one hits the 20 edit limit they can still edit the info for tags they create.

I just created two tags and can not edit the info.

At present it has been 22 hours with no checking of the tag edit queue.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I understand the pain of trying to carefully fill out tag wikis only to be met with a full queue that doesn’t get cleared for a long time. But, I still think it is better if the community reviews them rather than the SE staff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We won't be making a special case and changing the system for this site specifically.

And CMs do monitor this site on a daily basis, alongside the Substrate site which was launched into private Beta at the same time. We do have to attend to other tasks, though, so yesterday I didn't remember to go through the suggested edits queue — I just did it, though, so you should be set to suggest new edits.

Answer (score 5):

Users on private beta sites already have a plethora of privileges that they wouldn't usually get for several years on other sites in the SE network, such as being able to access the close-vote review queue. But being able to have more than 20 pending edits at a time is not one of them.

I think it is unlikely that the SE staff will make many changes to the already-established process for private beta sites, for a number of reasons. One of those reasons is that in each of 2020, 2021, and 2022 we have had only 1 or 2 private beta sites launched per year, which means that private betas happen rarely, so it's not very worthwhile for the SE developers to spend energy on changing any code. **Another reason is that private betas last for 2-4 weeks, which again means that any inconveniences we experience during this time are very temporary in the grand scheme of things.** There's more reasons I can write, but in this specific case of wanting to increase the pending-edit limit, [only one user](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors) has made more than 7 edits, so again it doesn't seem like something for which SE will want to devote a lot of resources. Last but not least, the reason you have so many pending edits is because you're the only one editing the tag wikis, and maybe it's good to limit this a bit because otherwise ***all tag wikis will be written by the same person.***

I am only speaking for myself though, and if SE staff do want to give more privileges to users of this private beta site, then I have no problem with that!

Comment: @GuyCoder wow! That edit was quite impactful! At present I'm going through the suggested edits queue and reviewing as many of them as I can, so hopefully you'll soon be under 20 pending edits again :)